# How to append json type data to new FormData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have an php file like this

```
<form id="f-comment" class="form" method="post" action="submit_img_comment.php">
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Publish" data-params='{"imageid":<?php echo $imageid; ?>}'>
</form>
```

I'm sending the form using jQuery ajax

```
$(document).on("submit", ".form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // what form are you submitting?
    var form = $("#" + e.target.id);

    // parameters to send along with data
    var params = $(this).data("params");

    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr("method"),
        url: "include/" + form.attr("action"),
        data: new FormData(this),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data['msg']);
    }).fail(function(data) {
        alert("Error: Ajax Failed.");
    }).always(function(data) {
        // always do the following, no matter if it fails or not
    })
});
```

So far so good.

The only thing missing is how to add the params to FormData. Any ideas?

Comment: you are confusing the submit button and form ... form is `this` , not the button

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any file uploads, so why are you sending the data like there is? All you seem to need is `data : $(this).serialize()`

Comment: @adeneo right know there isn't. If later there's a file upload, do i change the code all over again? Of course not.

Comment: @charlietfl Noap. I'm not confusing anything. Not sure what your point is...

Comment: the point is you are expecting `this` to be 2 different elements in your code. The form doesn't have data attributes and is `this`. The button is not `this`. `what form are you submitting? = $(this)`.

Comment: @charlietfl So what's the solution? I just want it to work

Comment: use `find()` for the button

Comment: ok,  did: var params = $("input[type=submit]", this).data("params"); console.log(params); and it works. Now, how do i send it along with FormData ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.append()`, see [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) ; adjusting selector at declaration of `params` to `$(input[type=submit], this)` , where `this` is the `form` and `.data()` references `.data()` at `input type="submit"` element

```
 $(document).on("submit", ".form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData("form", this);
    var params = $("input[type=submit]", this).data("params");
    data.append("params", params);
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr("method"),
        url: "include/" + form.attr("action"),
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data['msg']);
    }).fail(function(data) {
        alert("Error: Ajax Failed.");
    }).always(function(data) {
        // always do the following, no matter if it fails or not
    })
  })
```

Comment: what i did is the following: var data = new FormData(this); That seems to work ok.

Answer (score 0):

The object `FormData` are the method `append` which add new parameters to the object.

For example:

```
var FD = new FormData('id-form');
FD.append('name','value');
```

Comment: i want to add a json object that is found on data-params. This does not do it